# How does OAuth handle authorization?

Tags: performance, rest, architecture, oauth-2.0

We have implemented a RESTful API using RestEasy. Now we are planning to build our own OAuth implementation and will integrate it with our Rest API.

I do not fully understand how OAuth handles authorization of every request to the API. My understanding is as follows:

1. User is authenticated by the OAuth server before any REST API calls are made.
2. Every REST API call will contain a token. The REST API server validates this token with the OAuth server. If the token is valid then the server will return a response.

This should have an impact on performance as we are validating the token for each and every API request with the second server. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Don't. Really. If you don't understand OAuth and live and breath in the security space, you're going to mess it up. Doing auth right is Hard. Find a vendor implementation you can live with.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how you will define your REST API. Basically OAUTH call has following components.

**User**: Who makes a request.

**Provider**: Who holds user information and provide apis to access them.

**Consumer**: Who asks the user to authorize the consumer to make request to the apis.

The basic workflow is as follows,

1. User tries to access restricted resource from Consumer.
2. Consumer asks user to share some information about him.(scope)
3. User selects his identity provider.
4. Consumer should be known to the Provider.(Usually consumer register itself as an application/website in provider's portal)
5. Consumer redirects to the provider with his consumer_key and scopes.
6. User authorize the application and grants access to some of his resource.
7. Provider creates a token and redirects back to consumer.
8. Consumer exchanges this token and its identity to get a access_token for user.
9. Consumer uses the access_token to make authorize request to provider and asks few    information about user.
10. Provider sends those information to consumer.
11. Consumer verifies the information and user is logged into the system.

Now each token is generated against the scope and will be valid for some days. Token validation will be part of response from **Provider**.

In your system, you can store user data against token, so that we need not request Provider to send those information. But if you dont want to store user information certainly there will be additional calls.

Comment: I need to handle session timeout and token revoking if i stored user data against token. Can we attach memcache like datasource to Oauth server so that we can improve session validation perfomance.